# how to merge two array in php? [php]

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I created SUBJECTS TO BE TAKEN BY STUDENTS in "subject" table

**TABLE "SUBJECT"**

```
ID| SHORTNAME | SUBJECT_NAME 
1 | MT        | MATHEMATICS 
2 | ASC       | ADDITIONAL SCIENCE
```

The columns in this table are automatically generated into the table "MID_YEAR_EXAMINATION"

**TABLE "MID_YEAR_EXAMINATION"**

```
ID | STUDENT NAME | MT | ASC
```

The scores obtained by students in each subject are inserted in the table "MID_YEAR_EXAMINATION"

```
ID | STUDENT_NAME | MT | ASC
1  | ALEX         | 88 | 62
2  | ELLY         | 78 | 43
```

MY QUESTION is i have two arrays
**code2**

```
$input1= array(
    "id" => $row['ID'],
    "name" => $row['STUDENT_NAME']
);

$sel_query3="Select * from SUBJECT  ORDER BY SUBJECT_NAME";
$result3 = @mysqli_query($con,$sel_query3);
while($row2 = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){   
    $MP = $row2['SHORTNAME'];
    $m = $row['SUBJECT_NAME']; //TO GET student's score 
    in each subject
            $input2 = array($MP => $m); 
    }
}
Echo  json_encode($input2);
```

how to fix that arrays as follows with edit that code:

FROM

```
[
    "id"   => "1",
    "name" => "ALEX",
    "MT"   => "88"
]
[
    "id"   => "1",
    "name" => "ALEX",
    "ASC"  => "62"
]
```

TO

```
[
    "id"   => "1",
    "name" => "ALEX",
    "MT"   => "88",
    "ASC"  => "62"
]
```

("MT" and "ASC" merge in one array)

I need your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's `array_merge()` function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

If the source arrays are assigned to $a and $b, it's simply `$combined = array_merge( $a, $b );`

If $b has a different value for the same-named element in $a, the value from $b will win out.

```
$a = [
  "id"   => "1",
  "name" => "ALEX",
  "MT"   => "88"
];
$b = [
    "id"   => "1",
    "name" => "ALEX",
    "ASC"  => "62"
];
print_r( array_merge( $a, $b ) );
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => ALEX
    [MT] => 88
    [ASC] => 62
)
```

Comment: How to append  this marged arrays  to json file?

Comment: What happened when you tried that? ;-) (But yes... that looks right)